# ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-postgresql

I'm in the midst of setting up my Django project on Heroku. I have been following the documentation, but when I `foreman start` I receive an error that I can't quite figure out. I have set up my engine files, but it doesn't seem to want to work.

**Full traceback:**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 160, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 15, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Someone suggested using `./manage.py diffsettings` and showing the DATABASES part:

```
DATABASES = {'default': {'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'NAME': '', 'TEST_MIRROR': None, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'TEST_NAME': None, 'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC', 'TEST_COLLATION': None, 'PORT': '', 'HOST': '', 'USER': '', 'TEST_CHARSET': None, 'PASSWORD': '', 'OPTIONS': {}}}
```

I can't seem to figure out what it means, but it doesn't look right on the surface.

Here is part of my `settings.py` that I think could be relevant to this problem:

```py
import os
import dj_database_url

ON_HEROKU = os.environ.get('ON_HEROKU')
HEROKU_SERVER = os.environ.get('HEROKU_SERVER')

if ON_HEROKU:
    
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'postgresql',
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
            'USER': '',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
            'PORT': '',  
        }
    }


DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# only refers to the location where your static files should end up after running manage.py collectstatic. you shouldn't really need collectstatic) when developing locally
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (    
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static'),
)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are using the [`dj-database-url` module](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url) to set `DATABASES['default']`. Whatever comes before the line:

```
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

is meaningless as you replace your database configuration in its entirety. The `dj_database_url.config()` loads your database configuration from the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable, or returns `{}` if the variable is not set.

Judging by your error, you didn't set the `DATABASE_URL` at all. Judging by the code preceding the `dj_database_url.config()` line, you should not be using the `dj_database_url.config()` function *at all*.

If you did want to use it, at least build a default URL:

```
if ON_HEROKU:
    DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://<postgresql>'
else:
    DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')

DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=DATABASE_URL)}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use following setting for localhost

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'DatabaseName',
        'USER': 'DatabaseUserName',
        'PASSWORD': 'DatabaseUserpassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: But can you use it for production?

Answer (score 3):

Encountered this issue when running my github workflows with github actions. So I found the following work around:

```
POSTGRES_DB = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_DB") #database name
POSTGRES_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PASSWORD") # database user password
POSTGRES_USER = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_USER") # database username
POSTGRES_HOST = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_HOST") # database host
POSTGRES_PORT = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PORT") # database port


POSTGRES_READY = (
    POSTGRES_DB is not None
    and POSTGRES_PASSWORD is not None
    and POSTGRES_USER is not None
    and POSTGRES_HOST is not None
    and POSTGRES_PORT is not None
)

print(POSTGRES_READY)

if POSTGRES_READY:
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
            "NAME": POSTGRES_DB,
            "USER": POSTGRES_USER,
            "PASSWORD": POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
            "HOST": POSTGRES_HOST,
            "PORT": POSTGRES_PORT,
        }
    }
```

Then your `.env` file:

```
export DEBUG=True
export DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=CI_CD_TEST_KEY
export POSTGRES_USER=taxi
export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=taxi
export POSTGRES_DB=pdm
export POSTGRES_PORT=5432
export POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
```

Then run `source .env`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using `django-tenant-users` when running the command:

```
python manage.py setup_dtu_tenants
```

It was because I had a folder named "settings" inside my project folder at the same level as my `settings.py`. After removing this folder, the issue is gone.

Comment: Your answer does not seem to match the error message that appears in the code shared by @ApathyBear. Please, do read the question again.

Comment: This does not seem to answer this question, but it helped my with my problem. The problem was in having `myprojectname/settings/` folder for my settings and `apps/settings` app

Answer (score 0):

With **"Django==3.1.7"**, I got the same error when using the code below in **"settings.py"**:

```py
# "settings.py"

from django.db import connection 

print(connection.queries) # Causes error
```

So, I removed **"print(connection.queries)"** as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
# "settings.py"

from django.db import connection 

# print(connection.queries) # Causes error
```